# Flagging layout for mobile (iPhone 4) is challenging to use

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile, flagging

I tried flagging a few posts using the iPhone 4 / Mobile interface, and the layout far exceeds the screen size.

The initial box for flagging and closing looks good and survives a portrait to landscape switch well. The bug happens when choosing "exact duplicate" and the text input box exceeds the bounds of the screen.

This makes it very difficult to operate the buttons and provide a link to the dupe.  My attempts to pinch / zoom or scale my way out of this failed. Rotating the device to landscape helped a little, but it was still not very workable.

[image: portrait layout]

[image: landscape layout]

Mobile Safari on iOS 4.3.5 - no jailbreaks, no betas.

Answer (score 2):

A fix for this will go out with the next build.

Silly fixed width got carried over from the desktop site.

Comment: I must say - all the other flagging and close layouts are awesomely done on iOS. This was the only thing that seemed off (for now obvious reasons)

Comment: Also - do you prefer I report bugs here or the main meta? I've got some on chat to file...

Comment: @bmike - meta.SO is preferred (unless it's really obviously a site-specific one), but they all get looked at.

Comment: The field is sized properly, but the action button is now insensitive. I'll post on meta.SO with a screenshot